# The following classes could not be instantiated: com.google.ads.AdView

Tags: android, ads

I found several questions about this problem, but I couldn't find a solution for it.

I added this code to AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
  <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

and I added GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar to the library file.

also I added this code at the top of my xml page:

```
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

but it didn't work, it gives me this error message:

```
   The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView
```

and when I test the app in my phone it doesn't work.

Comment: First, You should not use this AdMob sdk anymore. Now it´s included in the google Play services Package here: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html. Second, how do You have included the library into Your project?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs right click the app > build path > libraries > add extra jars.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I downloaded the google Play services Package using SDK manager but still didn't work.

Comment: and how is now the exact error message with play service?

Comment: we need two things, after You are using now play services, please post Your manifest and the layout where You using the adview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have installed google play service from sdk manager. Now add below code in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" ></uses-permission>

 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

In your activity_name.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/questions_adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:minHeight="38px"
        android:minWidth="250px" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

In respective activity_name.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

AdView mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.questions_adView);   
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .build();
    if(mAdView!=null)
    {
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

Note after you install the google play service, Follow the below steps:

1. import it in workspace from adt-bundle-linux-x86_64- 20140702/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib.
2. right click project--properties -- android -- add -- select google-play-service from dialog prompted.
3. Clean project.

Hope this will help to resolve error.

Comment: I got this error:  AdRequest.Builder cannot be resolved to a type under this code new AdRequest.Builder()

Comment: Have you imported like this? import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

Comment: I think you can find google play service version /adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services here. Tell me if you have any further issues while integrating admob.

Comment: the error gone but the add doesnt show up, here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140658/admob-ads-doesnt-show-up?noredirect=1#comment40975394_26140658

Comment: Hi, please check out my answer for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140658/admob-ads-doesnt-show-up/26142239#26142239

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

to:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

It once solved my issue.