# admob ads doesn't show up

Tags: android, admob

I made a simple app and added inside it an ad but it doesn't show up in the device.

and there is no errors in my code:

xml page:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" 
 >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ad_ip" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" ></uses-permission>    


 <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="4.3.23" />

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"                
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Comment: can You show Your manifest?

Comment: did you add the jar file for it?

Comment: @user3243147 yes I did

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I will add it in the question

Comment: can you show your manifest?

Comment: Do you have any error in logcat? Are are you implementing the AdView in your activity?

Comment: @donniezazen there is no any error in the logcat and I didn't put AdView in the java file.

Comment: and a simple question: do You have an internet connection? Because without this You will see no adview

Comment: @Opiatefuchs :) of course I have, but could the problem be from the admob ad itself ?

Comment: Please add also the code where you load the ad

Comment: @donfuxx you mean the code from the java file ? because I only used the code adView in the xml page

Comment: with gms admob you have to load ads programmatically now, see https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration and the @Opiatefuchs answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ad_ip" >
```

1) The xmlns attribute should be like this and in my case I have placed in  the root tag of xml file.

```
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

2) Check, you have given the actual adUnitId from admob account.

Hope this will help you, if any further problems, you can ask.

Comment: it didn't work, I found this error in the graphical layout: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView failed to instantiate.

Comment: please see the edited answer. I have changed first point. I think now the error will resolve.

Comment: but its the same code I tried it and still didn't work, do I need to any code in the java file ?

Comment: thanks, it worked I had to use newer version of eclipse.

Comment: Are you kidding? It is not related to eclipse version at all. Android & Admob work fine even in Eclipse Indigo (!) @abdullatifmorsi

Comment: @donfuxx not because its new, because in Eclipse Indigo I saved on it old admob sdk data with new google services data, thats why I downloaded new Eclipse to start from the beginning.

Comment: Lol ok, would have been easier though to just remove the old admob sdk @abdullatifmorsi

Answer (score 2):

At  the beginning I had made the same mistake, I only used the xml file and didn´t load the view in my Activity. So just put this inisde the activity:

```
     AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
     adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: I added the code but this time the app didn't work in my phone or in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the wrong `xmlns` attribute inside your adview (it refers to **legacy admob**):

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"
```

you should only use the following which refers to Google Play Admob:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

==> remove the wrong `xmlns` attribute

Comment: what is in the logcat? I mean not only errors.. are there any warnings / infos coming from admob? Admob tells you when something went wrong in the logcat

Comment: where are you actually loading the ad? I mean you do have something like `adView.loadAd(adRequest);` in your Activity, do you?

Comment: I get this error message in the graphical layout: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView failed to instantiate.

Comment: Could you please provide the full stacktrace from logcat? There can be various reasons for `failed to instantiate`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

XML:

```
       <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="your key ID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Add following code in your manifest:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: I got this message (error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'loadAdOnCreate' in package

Comment: the error is from this attribute:  ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"

Comment: he´s using the google play service library, but Your example is from the old admob sdk

Comment: yes he can, but not with the importet admob library. And, the google play service is replacing the old admob sdk, so it is recommended to use the play service